# How to communicate with the users of an extension?

Tags: extension, developer, compatiblity

We are discussing about which version(s) to maintain compatibility with, and would like to be able to discuss that with the users of that extension. Is there an easy way to do that?

Eg. civicrm.org has already several ways to display a message to the civicrm users (eg. community message), would it be possible to plug into that and add a special message only visible to those that have a specific extension enabled?

Comment: Is there some way to do this via an extension update? e.g. include code that issues a warning to admins? i know that's a 1-off and not everybody will update regularly...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

Per [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/jgowans/behind-civicrm%E2%80%99s-in-app-messages), only the core team can control in-app messages.  I'd say you'd have to make your appeal directly to them.  I'm sure they'd be hesitant (with good reason), but you may be able to make your case.

However, that wouldn't do any good in your case.  I've just skimmed CRM/Core/CommunityMessages.php.  The `pick` method allows message display to be controlled by the permission of the logged-in user and by the components that are enabled (e.g. CiviMail) - but not by extension.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a new feature request for this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18541

Comment: It seems that feature requests like this are better received in the forums than in the Jira DB.  My understanding is that unless there is active development and/or funding, feature requests aren't put into Jira.